# data.table group by multiple columns using grepl?

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I need to group a data.table by 30 columns.

Rather than list each column name, can I use a regular expression like grepl for the ***by*** argument?

Below is a minimum reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)

library(data.table)

data <- diamonds %>% cbind("Another Column" = diamonds$cut == "Ideal") %>% data.table

data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = list(carat, cut, color, clarity, depth, table, price, `Another Column`)]
```

I have already tried the following

```
data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = colnames(data) %>% .[!grepl(pattern = "^[a-z]$", .)] %>% as.list]
```

Update:

- please use pattern **^[a-z]$**
- sum column x, y, z by carat, cut, color, clarity, depth, table, price, Another Column

Comment: What is the "pattern" in column name that you are looking for? Also note that regex varies for each case, so if this is not your real data and real column names chances are that the answer would not work on your real data.

Comment: please use the regex from minimum reproducible example, the pattern is under **I have already tried the following**.

Comment: Do you want to group by those numerical columns? or sum them? `data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
     .SDcols = grep(pattern = "^[a-z]$", names(data), value = TRUE)]
` ?

Comment: sum column **x**, **y**, **z** by **carat**, **cut**, **color**, **clarity**, **depth**, **table**, **price**, **`Another Column`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better way, but wrapping an expression returning character column names with `eval` or `c` (`c` used below) works

```
set.seed(2019)
df <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(1:2, 100, T), 10 , 10)) %>% 
        setnames(c(letters[1:3], paste0('zebra', 1:7)))

names(df)
# [1] "a"      "b"      "c"      "zebra1" "zebra2" "zebra3" "zebra4" "zebra5" "zebra6"
# [10] "zebra7"

df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = c(grep('^[a-z]$', names(df), value = TRUE))]

#   a b c zebra1 zebra2 zebra3 zebra4 zebra5 zebra6 zebra7
# 1: 2 2 1      2      2      1      1      1      1      2
# 2: 2 2 2      1      1      1      1      1      2      2
# 3: 1 1 2      3      3      2      4      2      4      3
# 4: 2 1 1      3      3      2      3      3      2      3
# 5: 1 2 1      2      3      3      4      4      3      4
# 6: 2 1 2      1      2      2      1      1      2      1
# 7: 1 2 2      1      2      2      1      2      2      2
```

Edit: For example in question

```
data[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = c(grep('^[a-z]$', names(data), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))]

#        carat       cut color clarity depth table price Another Column    x    y    z
#     1:  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326           TRUE 3.95 3.98 2.43
#     2:  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326          FALSE 3.89 3.84 2.31
#     3:  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327          FALSE 4.05 4.07 2.31
#     4:  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334          FALSE 4.20 4.23 2.63
#     5:  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335          FALSE 4.34 4.35 2.75
#    ---                                                                              
# 53133:  0.72     Ideal     D     SI1  60.8    57  2757           TRUE 5.75 5.76 3.50
# 53134:  0.72      Good     D     SI1  63.1    55  2757          FALSE 5.69 5.75 3.61
# 53135:  0.70 Very Good     D     SI1  62.8    60  2757          FALSE 5.66 5.68 3.56
# 53136:  0.86   Premium     H     SI2  61.0    58  2757          FALSE 6.15 6.12 3.74
# 53137:  0.75     Ideal     D     SI2  62.2    55  2757           TRUE 5.83 5.87 3.64
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I use **data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = colnames(data) %>% .[!grepl(pattern = "^[a-z]$", .)] %>% eval]** in my minimum reproducible example, it does not work.

Comment: I think it doesn't work with `%>%` because data.table is specifically looking for an expression in the form `c(...)` or `eval(...)`. See my edit for how to achieve the result with your example data.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there a difference between **dt[, sum(x), by = list(y, z)]** and **dt[, sum(x), by = c("y", "z")]**

Comment: Those will give the same output.